# Getting both iOS and Android hats

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

Would it be possible to get hats for both Android and iOS or is it limited to having one or the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course it's possible. The real problem is figuring out how to convince your iOS-device-owning friends to lend you their phones and let you install an app for a second...

Comment: I've got my boss' iPad next to me actually. It's either destiny or the end of my career I suppose.

Comment: @fivedigit Destiny. Definitely destiny. :P